# switch mysql column value from '0' to '1'?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a list of user reviews that a user can choose to approve or delete.
I have the reviews.php file which lists the pending reviews, a approve_review.php file and a delete_review.php file.

Once the user approves the review i need the mysql column 'approve' to be changed from '0' to '1'. Same applies for the delete but instead of updating 'approve' it will update 'delete'.

Everything i've tried isn't working. please can someone tell me where i'm going wrong. Thanks.

reviews.php:

```
<?php
    $pending_set = get_pending_reviews();
    while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($pending_set)) {
?>
        <div class="prof-content-pend-reviews" id="reviews">
            <div class="pend-review-content">
                <?php echo "{$reviews['content']}"; ?>
            </div>
            <a href="includes/approve_review.php"><div class="approve"></div></a>
            <a href="includes/delete_review.php"><div class="delete"></div></a>    
        </div>
<? }  ?>
```

approve_review.php:

```
<?php
    require_once("session.php"); 
    require_once("functions.php");
    require('_config/connection.php');
    approve_review ($_GET['review'], $_SESSION['user']);
    header('Location: http://localhost/ptb1/reviews.php');
?>
```

Function:

```
function approve_review($review_id, $user) {
    global $connection;
    global $_SESSION;
    $query = "UPDATE ptb_reviews
            SET approved='1'
            WHERE id=$review_id 
            AND to_user_id=$user";
    mysql_query($query, $connection);           
}
```

Comment: What are the types of $review_id and $user?  If they are strings, then you need o enclose them in single quotes.  Also, did you try printing the result of $query to ensure it's properly formed, then feeding it into mysql manually to see what it does?

Comment: I'm not sure how's your db is organised by do you really need the `AND to_user_id=$user` line?

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is missing to approve_review.php ... its has to be something like this:

```
<a href="includes/approve_review.php?review=TheID"><div class="approve"></div></a>
```

You have to replace TheID with your php variable.

Greatings!

Comment: i did that and it still won't update anything: <a href="includes/approve_review.php?review=<?php echo $review['user_id']; ?>"><div class="approve"></div></a>

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong here:

- You are not actually sending any parameters to your script;
- Your script is wide open to sql injection, you should switch to prepared statements in PDO / mysqli.